# Blender Freezing computer Since updating to 3.3

Tags: modeling, performance

I've updated my blender from 3.2 to 3.3, I have finally been able to sculpt a head I can be proud of and wanted to give it hair with the new system.

At first, it opened fine, But coming back a few hours later from lunch and the problems started.

blender became progressively laggier and crashed more frequently (I had saved the file and shut down the laptop before leaving). the next day my laptop started freezing solid when trying to open the file. my laptop needed to be shut down by holding the power button,
note that it wasn't the program to freeze as that would mean windows would report "blender isn't responding". instead, it freezes up everything.

my laptop specifications:

- Intel i7 10th gen CPU
- 16GB ram
- RTX 2060 GPU

This problem seems to occur in any file with a large enough poly count, mainly my sculpting files.
I can still open the file in blender 3.2 without any issues.

While my blender struggles, my other demanding programs and games work fine and I do not have any other programs open other than a chrome tab while using blender. And all my drivers and other updates are updated to their latest version.

File I refer to in this question:

[image]

Comment: Your sculpted head has a *Subdivision Surface* modifier on it. It is a bad idea to add this modifier to a triangulated sculpted mesh => lot of calculations, and lag. Remove the *Subdivision Surface* modifier from the sculpt.

Comment: @Blunder although I had mentioned in my post that 3.2 did open the file, it now refuses to open my sculpt files too. If it did open for you, could you remove the modifier and post it? It would help me greatly! (I haven't worked on my file)

Comment: Yes, it takes a while to open the file. Did you press Ctrl+1 by accident? This adds a Subdivision Surface modifier level 1 to the selected object. [Here is the file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E7x4abkBYlHEnB_QugzJRC4714EwXkbI/view) without the modifier.